# Shared element transition not showing on top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, transition, android-transitions

I'm trying to run a shared element transition from a recycler view to a detail view containing a pager. Pretty much the same as in this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=9ab163eeaa-androidweekly-298&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-9ab163eeaa-338153205).

Everything works, except that the back-from-detail-to-overview animation is clipped to the overview recycler view cells.

After watching this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L4fLrWDvAU), I learned, that unless `setSharedElementsUseOverlay` is set to `false` on the activity's window, the transitions will run on an overlay that's on top of *everything* - the whole content of the activity if I understood correctly. So it should not be possible that the transition is hidden or clipped.

I searched both for `setSharedElementsUseOverlay` and `windowSharedElementsUseOverlay` in my project and didn't find anything. The default is supposed to be `true`. I also tried setting it explicitly to `true`, both in the theme and programmatically and nothing... the transition is still clipped!

I tried to cause the clipping with the demo project from the blog post, and also wasn't able to - setting `setSharedElementsUseOverlay` to `false` doesn't cause any clipping. I ensured that no view in the whole project has `clipChildren` or `clipPadding` set to false.

I have no idea what else to do. I tried debugging Android's sources but the transitions classes are unwieldy and I couldn't even find where the overlay view is used. The only thing that I get working in my project is setting `clipChildren` and `clipPadding` to false all the way up in the hierarchy, but this is not what I want - besides of undesired side effects (even when doing it temporarily as it may overwrite non-defaults of parents) it also doesn't cause the effect I want without further tweaking, as now overlay views of the shared element appear on top during the transition.

Well, I can step by step modify the example project until it's the same as my actual project, but this is a very tedious task as the actual project is very large and complex. I have done some changes that seem relevant, like adding intermediate views and so on. No success so far.

I simply want to use the overlay. What can be the reason for it not working? Or at least how can I debug this?

I've reproduced this so far on Android M and N. Haven't tested on any other versions.

Comment: So you provide a fallback for pre lollipop devices?

Comment: @Xenolion I've not checked pre-lollipop yet. How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: Depending on your question what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @Xenolion I've been testing on Android M and N. Added this to the post.